# Thymeleaf: Unexpected token ';'

Tags: spring-boot, var, unexpected-token

When I tried to parse the DB into a webpage, it shown the error: $orderStatusCount is not defined.
This is my Repository:

```
@Query(
    value="select status,count(id) from orders group by status",
    nativeQuery=true
)
public List<Object> reportByStatus();
```

And this is my js part in webpage:

```
<th:block layout:fragment="script">
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        console.log([[${orderStatusCount}]]);
    </script>
    <script>
        var transaction = [[${orderStatusCount}]];
        var transaction_x = transaction.map(x => x["status"]);
        var transaction_y = transaction.map(x => x["count(id)"]);
        var xValues = transaction_x;
        var yValues = transaction_y;
        var barColors = [
            "#b91d47",
            "#00aba9",
            "#2b5797",
            "#e8c3b9",
            "#1e7145"
        ];

        new Chart("myChart", {
            //Some stuff here
        });
    </script>
</th:block>
```

It's still return right when I console.log() it, but I have some trouble with the transaction var.
What should I do? Thank you.